# How to identify test case of libfuzzer

Tags: libfuzzer, php-src

I'm running libfuzzer for PHP source code and I have results NEW_FUNC. As I understand it shows uncovered "features".

```
#54234  REDUCE cov: 10954 ft: 52339 corp: 9636/8748Kb lim: 5819 exec/s: 1023 rss: 79Mb L: 280/5819 MS: 2 ChangeByte-EraseBytes-
        NEW_FUNC[1/1]: 0xaaaab50687f8 in zend_hash_packed_grow /php-src/Zend/zend_hash.c:312
```

I want to get the test case for this trace, however with the files named like `0aaea2b53ceef682d7eb2dbe0a27f20ba8f3ca24` it's not clear to me where I should look and I have over 20k such files created. Is this even feasible to find or that's not the purpose of libfuzzer?

The fuzzer I run for the reference:
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/sapi/fuzzer/fuzzer-parser.c

Comment: Why would you want to get that specific test case, instead you can choose a test case from finally generated corpus to find the one hitting this function maybe via a breakpoint or something.
And finally generated test cases would be even better as libfuzzer would try more mutations and save the best ones only.

Comment: I was running this fuzzer for a few hours and didn't get any new test cases. That's why I was interested in cases finding new paths. And fuzzer already has a corpus generated from existing tests. I wanted to improve the test coverage.

Comment: Theoretically I think fuzzer would be saving the input generating NEW_FUNC to the corpus.